# Connectivity issue with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Internet not accessible

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I am sorry if it seems a very naive question, but I am not so experienced in Linux.
I was installing something, when I accidently removed some important packages in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. after that, I lost my Gnome and many functionalities like network connection. I even could not connect to my router.

First I need to fix internet connection. So I did a lot of research and did the following in my interface and dns settings:

```
ip link show
```

the result shows `eno1` as my router interface name. then I did as below:

```
sudo ip link set eno1 up
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev eno1
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

after this my connection to the router was resolved. I checked it with:

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

then I changed my dns settings this way:

```
sudo nano /etc/resovl.conf
```

and added these lines to it:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

but I still could not connect to internet. I checked it with:

```
ping google.com
```

I also checked my firewall with this command and it is not active:

```
sudo ufw status
```

also using this command I see that port forwarding is enabled:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

notes:

- my pc is connected to the router via ethernet cable
- I also do not have network-manager.service in my system

How can I fix my internet connection?

Comment: "my pc is connected to the router via ethernet cable" What is the ip-address of that router?  Maybe you need to change the default route to that ip-address, and not to your local ip-address .

Comment: Showing the commands you executed, **without** the results, error messages, etc. conveys no information. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: @waltinator which output do you require?

Comment: @Luuk the ip address of the router is 192.168.1.1/24 . I mentioned above that I changed default route to it.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> sudo ip link set eno1 up
> sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev eno1
> sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
> ```

You set your *LOCAL* ip address to 192.168.1.1. That's the IP of your router according to your question and comments... Your computer should be in the same subnet, but *not* duplicate of your routers IP. Set it to something unique, for instance `192.168.1.10/24`.

The rest is fine, so simply replace `sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev eno1` with `sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev eno1`, and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Correct! You are totally right.

Comment: If you researched that as a newcomer to Linux, you should be proud of your achievement. You show more initiative than a lot of techies I've met...